# How to add readable subtitles in iMovie?

Tags: imovie, subtitle

I'm using iMovie 10.1.13 on 2015 macbook running OX 10.14.6 I'm trying to put some subtitles below the movie to make for my poor English pronunciation or to allow viewers to view without sound.
I'm using the title section, using the "third lower part", and I create a new section for every single line of subtitles.

I change the font size, color (My background is completely white so I want to settle with all black fonts). This works well for the first titles but after inserting a few sections, the space size between characters decrease and becomes less (when previewing and full export) readable and seems to double when editing the text:
Normal pictures:
[image: Pretty readable]
This is quite readable

[image: Less readable]
This is less readable

[image: Edit the less readable]
Edit the less readable

Is there a way to preserve the character space, and keep the subtitles readable?

Comment: What do you mean by "after a while?" Also are you exporting the movies to a stand alone movie file? If so what if you increase the quality of the export?

Comment: Apparently a bug in imovie: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250355925

Answer (score 1):

And it is solved! I just installed version 10.1.14 and it looks very sharp: 15 subtitles in a sequence! Strangely enough the release notes did not mention this behaviour.